# Ribbon binding failures when used within a regular Window (not a RibbonWindow)

Tags: wpf, binding, .net-3.5, ribbon

I'm using a Ribbon control from RibbonControlLibrary for .net 3.5.

I can't use `RibbonWindow` for some presentation-compatibility issues. So I place a Ribbon control inside `Window`.

There are no visible issues, but I'm getting 2 error messages in my VisualStudio output window.

Those messages are:

> 1. System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>      reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>      AncestorType='Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonWindow',
>      AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=WindowState; DataItem=null;
>      target element is 'Ribbon' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget'
>      (type 'Object')
> 2. System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>      reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>      AncestorType='Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonWindow',
>      AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=IsActive; DataItem=null;
>      target element is 'Ribbon' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget'
>      (type 'Object')

This can be reproduced just adding a `Ribbon` to a `Window` and running the application.

**Is there a way to tell Ribbon not to try to bind anything exactly to RibbonWindow but for Window?**

Comment: I **DO NOT** use RibbonWindow, I place a Ribbon onto regular WPF Window, that's the point. RibbonWindow looks and behaves a bit different and those difference is unacceptable in my app.

Comment: I'm using System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon against .NET 472 and its the same. But I'm not sure if these errors cause any real issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find source for binding with reference with RibbonComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842134/cannot-find-source-for-binding-with-reference-with-ribboncombobox)

Answer (score -1):

Since you said you can't use RibbonWindow (for some reason...), I am assuming you're doing something like

```
<Window x:Class="Yournamespace" ...>
    <Ribbon>
    </Ribbon>
</Window>
```

Your ancestor should be 
    `AncestorType='System.Windows.Window'` and not `'Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonWindow'`

Comment: I understand the reason, but I don't know how to solve the issue. AFAIK some control's template inside Ribbon can be overridden in the outer style to make it look at AncestorType of Window instead of RibbonWindow.

Comment: May be I misunderstand Your answer, but it seems your advice is not to mind those binding issues.

Answer (score -3):

You probably have:

```
<Window x:Class="yournamespace" 
    xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
...>
    <r:Ribbon>
    </r:Ribbon>
</Window>

To fix this just replace <Window> and </Window> with <r:RibbonWindow> and </r:RibbonWindow>
```

this fixed it for me

Comment: if I could use RibbonWindow there would be no questions. My question says "I can't use RibbonWindow for some presentation-compatibility issues"

Comment: If you could give an example of your basic code when you use ribbonwindow and the error it generates, we could maybe see where stuff goes wrong. For me the error went away when I used ribbonwindow. I find it strange that you can't use it