# Cannot find source for binding with reference with RibbonComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ribbon

I'm trying to learn WPF and seem to be getting an error I really don't fully understand.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonWindow', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=WindowState; DataItem=null; target element is 'Ribbon' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonWindow', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=IsActive; DataItem=null; target element is 'Ribbon' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

Here a section of my XAML. I can't tell if the errors just started, but I have been tweaking code that works with the two `RibbonComboBoxe`es under the *Home* header. (The `<Ribbon>` element is in a `<Grid>` element.)

Can anyone help me to try and resolve this issue? The code isn't quite behaving correctly and I can't tell if this error is related.

```
<Ribbon>
    <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <RibbonApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="_Preview" ImageSource="Images/preview.png"></RibbonApplicationMenuItem>
            <RibbonSeparator></RibbonSeparator>
            <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Name="Save" KeyTip="S" Header="_Save" ImageSource="Images/save.png" ToolTipTitle="Save" ToolTipDescription="Save the current article and keep editing" Click="Save_Click"></RibbonApplicationMenuItem>
            <RibbonSeparator></RibbonSeparator>
            <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Name="SaveAndExit" KeyTip="X" Header="Save and E_xit" ToolTipTitle="Save and Exit" ToolTipDescription="Save the current article and close window" Click="SaveAndExit_Click"></RibbonApplicationMenuItem>
            <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Name="AbortAndExit" Header="_Abort Edit" ToolTipTitle="Abort Edit" ToolTipDescription="Close window without saving changes to this article" Click="AbortAndExit_Click"></RibbonApplicationMenuItem>
        </RibbonApplicationMenu>
    </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
    <RibbonTab Header="Home">
        <RibbonGroup Header="Category">
            <RibbonComboBox Label="Category:" SelectionBoxWidth="250">
                <RibbonGallery SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Categories.SelectedItem}">
                    <RibbonGalleryCategory IsSharedColumnSizeScope="True" DisplayMemberPath="Text" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Categories.Items}">
                    </RibbonGalleryCategory>
                </RibbonGallery>
            </RibbonComboBox>
            <RibbonComboBox Label="Subcategory:" SelectionBoxWidth="250">
                <RibbonGallery SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Subcategories.SelectedItem}">
                    <RibbonGalleryCategory IsSharedColumnSizeScope="True" ColumnsStretchToFill="True" MaxColumnCount="1" DisplayMemberPath="Text" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Subcategories.Items}">
                    </RibbonGalleryCategory>
                </RibbonGallery>
            </RibbonComboBox>
            <RibbonButton Label="Edit Categories" Command="local:EditCommands.Categories" SmallImageSource="Images\categories_sm.png" ToolTipTitle="Edit Categories" ToolTipDescription="Add, edit or delete categories and subcategories" ToolTipImageSource="Images\categories_sm.png"></RibbonButton>
        </RibbonGroup>
        <RibbonGroup Header="Author">
            <RibbonTwoLineText Text="jwood@softcircuits.com"></RibbonTwoLineText>
            <RibbonButton Label="Set Author" Command="local:EditCommands.Header1" SmallImageSource="Images\h1_sm.png" ToolTipTitle="Header 1" ToolTipDescription="Format selected text as a level 1 header" ToolTipImageSource="Images\h1.png"></RibbonButton>
        </RibbonGroup>
        <RibbonGroup Header="Settings">
            <RibbonCheckBox Name="chkApproved" Label="Approved"></RibbonCheckBox>
            <RibbonCheckBox Name="chkDeprecated" Label="Deprecated"></RibbonCheckBox>
            <RibbonButton Name="btnMetadata" Label="Metadata" SmallImageSource="Images\metadata_sm.png" ToolTipTitle="Metadata" ToolTipDescription="Edit article metadata" ToolTipImageSource="Images\metadata.png" Click="btnMetadata_Click"></RibbonButton>
        </RibbonGroup>
        <RibbonGroup Header="History">
            <RibbonButton Label="Edit Updates" Command="local:EditCommands.EditHistory" SmallImageSource="Images\history_sm.png" LargeImageSource="Images\history.png" ToolTipTitle="Edit Updates" ToolTipDescription="Edit update history for this article"></RibbonButton>
        </RibbonGroup>
    </RibbonTab>
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on IlVic's answer, I changed my `Window` to a `RibbonWindow`. But then I'm getting the following error.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'RibbonGalleryItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is cause by your `Ribbon` control. If you take a look to its default style (you can use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)), you will find this [MultiDataTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<rd:MultiDataTrigger>
    <rd:MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <rd:Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ribbon:RibbonWindow}, Path=IsActive}" Value="False" />
        <rd:Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(SystemParameters.IsGlassEnabled)}" Value="False" />
        <rd:Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsHostedInRibbonWindow}" Value="True" />
    </rd:MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <rd:Setter TargetName="PART_TitleHost" Value="{windows:DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveCaptionTextBrushKey}}" Property="TextElement.Foreground" />
</rd:MultiDataTrigger>
```

As you can see its first condition is looking for an ancestor whose type is [RibbonWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonwindow(v=vs.110).aspx).
You will easly find another `MultiDataTrigger` which as a condition that looks for `WindowState` property of a `RibbonWindow` control too.

I guess that your XAML is put inside a normal Window. So you need to replace the `Window` object with a `RibbonWindow` one, something like:

```
<rib:RibbonWindow
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:rib="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
        x:Class="[yourWindowClassName]">
    <!-- Put your Ribbon Control somewhere here -->
</rib:RibbonWindow>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I needed that. I still need to learn quite a bit about WPF and XAML. I've marked your answer as the correct one but if you wouldn't mind taking a look, I am now getting a similar but different error after the change. Is `RibbonGalleryItem` an element I _must_ manually add to my XAML?

Comment: I am sorry @JonathanWood, but I am not able to reproduce your second issue. Probably you should add more details (maybe you can consider to create a new question) regarding you XAML and your code.